# WPF enum binding do not refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, enums

So basically I have an ObservableCollection of objects that is bound to WPF datagrid.
Problem is with enum type property - SyncState - it won't refresh in the grid row but the tooltip of it refreshes correctly.

XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SyncState}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Stan">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SyncState}" />
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Object Class:

```
class TechnologyFile
{
    public string TechName { get; private set; }
    public string FilePath { get; private set; }
    public DateTime FileDate { get; set; }
    public AuxFunctions.SyncState SyncState { get; set; }
}
```

Effect:

[image: grid view]

As You can see - Tooltip is correct - SyncState is indeed "NoFile". Why datagrid row says something different?

Comment: Your TechnologyFile class must implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and the set method of the property SyncState must raise the PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever a property's value is changed.

I imagine that the tooltip is correct, because it requests the value from the object at the time it is shown and thus at a time when the property has the changed value.

Comment: Thank You :)
I was thinking about that but the fact that tooltip worked as intended mislead me.